# Onclick Command that Edits the HTML of a Pop Window

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I'm pretty new to JavaScript so I'm not sure how to do the following.

Basically the following line is what I'm going for:

```
<a onclick="JavascriptFunction(0000000)"><img src="image1.png"></a>
```

The `0000000` you see needs to be the special code at the end of a youtube videos link, so it needs to be different each time i use it, for example:

```
<a onclick="JavascriptFunction(0000000)"><img src="image1.png"></a>
<a onclick="JavascriptFunction(0000001)"><img src="image2.png"></a>
<a onclick="JavascriptFunction(0000002)"><img src="image3.png"></a>
```

What I would like the JavaScript function to do is make a pop window, with the same width and height of a YouTube video, and edit the HTML in that window to have the corresponding video.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0000000"></iframe>
```

What I'm after really is a page with all our video reviews we do for our company, we click the thumbnail for the product and the `popWin()` comes up with the video they were looking for. I understand I can make a few pages with the right videos and use the `onclick="popWin()"` to open the right ones, but we have a lot of videos to put on this page, so is there a way to have one page and change the code in the `iframe` to be the correct video?

Just a heads up since this is for a company, I only have access to the HTML page and nothing else, so long as I can put a function in the head section that is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/wLxb3vuy/1/) JSFiddle

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:setVideo('yzpUKET1Ki0')">Video 1</a><br/>
<a href="javascript:setVideo('h8zIfkMp08U')">Video 2</a><br/>
<a href="javascript:setVideo('yG29lnYRuVk')">Video 3</a><br/>
<iframe id="youtube" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0000000"></iframe>
```

JavaScript

```
function setVideo(video) {
    document.getElementById("youtube").src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video;
}
```

So.. Give your `iframe` an `id`, and change the `src` attribute of that.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot, i didn't think it was so simple! There's one small problem though, in Firefox and IE, the onclick opens a new blank window instead of swapping the src, do you know of any fixes for this?

Comment: @TylerCourt do you have `href="javascript:..."`? Maybe you could try with styled `<label>` instead of `<a>`. I can't reproduce this in firefox with my example in JSFiddle, could you provide the example where this happens?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply @Arg0n, I was able to use a button with the an onclick="setVideo('KFIbBbj90Ms') instead, that seemed to fix the issue in all the browsers, Thanks for the help. As for the issue that was coming up, see the imgur link here, it was basically opening a blank tab when i clicked the link, happend in both IE and Firefox. http://i.imgur.com/QnQVhhh.png Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

include these references. you can get the popup from bootstarap modal popup

1. jquery reference
2. bootstrap js reference
3. bootstrap css reference

ref: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){
    $("#iframeYoutube").attr("src","#");
  })
  
})

function changeVideo(vId){
  var iframe=document.getElementById("iframeYoutube");
  iframe.src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+vId;

  $("#myModal").modal("show");
}
```

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"   integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a onclick="changeVideo('e80BbX05D7Y')">video-1</a>
<a onclick="changeVideo('ReRcHdeUG9Y')">video-2</a>



<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
      
        <iframe id="iframeYoutube" width="560" height="315"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/e80BbX05D7Y" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i have return this solution in codepen checkout:http://codepen.io/rajashekar2012/pen/dMrodq